# Checksum failure and readings of 16962 over and over

Tags: c++, arduino-uno, adafruit

I am working on creating a program that receives data from a plantower 5003 and writes it to an SD card using Adafruit Data Logger Sheild and an Arduino Uno board. It is powered by an external battery pack, as the goal is to be able to set it up in a house and let it collect data for ~2 days, or until the battery runs out. I only want it to print out date, time, 2.5ppm, 10ppm, 3um, 5um.

Currently, it will print data to the SD card just fine for about the first 30 measurments, but then will spit out "16962" over and over, and occasionally return to a normal reading(~10-30 in my house) for one line, then go back to 16962.

It also prints to the serial monitor around 4 good readings, then a checksum failure.

```
//The first few readings may be all 0's due to the sensor needing to start up
//but the SD card starts before it so it writes 0's since the sensor is not awake yet
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"


//Real time clock
RTC_PCF8523 rtc;
//The data enterss with pin 0, and writes to pin 10
SoftwareSerial pmsSerial(0, 10);
//SD pin is 10 with the sheild
const int chipSelect = 10;
void setup() {
  // our debugging output
  Serial.begin(19200);

  // sensor baud rate is 9600

  pmsSerial.begin(9600);

 Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");

  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");
//opens CSV file
File csvFile = SD.open("datalog2.csv", FILE_WRITE);

if (csvFile) {

//Headers for the data
csvFile.println("Date,Time,25PPM,100PPM,03UM,05UM");
   csvFile.close();
}
//Start the RTC
rtc.begin();

    //Uncomment if you need to reset the time and date from a computer -> should only have to if the coin cell battery dies(~5 years)
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
}
//Sets up the Plantower 5003 info
struct pms5003data {
  uint16_t framelen;
  uint16_t pm10_standard, pm25_standard, pm100_standard;
  uint16_t pm10_env, pm25_env, pm100_env;
  uint16_t particles_03um, particles_05um, particles_10um, particles_25um, particles_50um, particles_100um;
  uint16_t unused;
  uint16_t checksum;
};

struct pms5003data data;


void loop() {
  //Calls the RTC at the moment just before printing to get a snapshot of the current time
DateTime now = rtc.now();

File csvFile = SD.open("datalog3.csv", FILE_WRITE);
if (csvFile) {
  //printing the date, time, and PPM info to a CSV file that can be opened in Excel
    csvFile.print(now.year());
          csvFile.print("/"); 
    csvFile.print(now.month());   
          csvFile.print("/");
    csvFile.print(now.day());
           csvFile.print(",");

    csvFile.print(now.hour());
          csvFile.print(":"); 
    csvFile.print(now.minute());   
          csvFile.print(":"); 
    csvFile.print(now.second());  
          csvFile.print(",");

    csvFile.print(data.pm25_standard);
          csvFile.print(",");
    csvFile.print(data.pm100_standard);
          csvFile.print(",");
    csvFile.print(data.particles_03um);
          csvFile.print(",");
    csvFile.println(data.particles_05um);

    csvFile.close();
}

// Telling it to collect/write data every 1 second (1000) , or 60 seconds (60000)
delay(1000);


  if (readPMSdata(&pmsSerial)) {

    //Prints to serial monitor
   // reading data was successful!
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("---------------------------------------");
    Serial.println("Concentration Units (standard)");
    Serial.print("PM 1.0: "); Serial.print(data.pm10_standard);
    Serial.print("\t\tPM 2.5: "); Serial.print(data.pm25_standard);
    Serial.print("\t\tPM 10: "); Serial.println(data.pm100_standard);
    Serial.println("---------------------------------------");
    Serial.println("Concentration Units (environmental)");
    Serial.print("PM 1.0: "); Serial.print(data.pm10_env);
    Serial.print("\t\tPM 2.5: "); Serial.print(data.pm25_env);
    Serial.print("\t\tPM 10: "); Serial.println(data.pm100_env);
    Serial.println("---------------------------------------");
    Serial.print("Particles > 0.3um / 0.1L air:"); Serial.println(data.particles_03um);
    Serial.print("Particles > 0.5um / 0.1L air:"); Serial.println(data.particles_05um);
    Serial.print("Particles > 1.0um / 0.1L air:"); Serial.println(data.particles_10um);
    Serial.print("Particles > 2.5um / 0.1L air:"); Serial.println(data.particles_25um);
    Serial.print("Particles > 5.0um / 0.1L air:"); Serial.println(data.particles_50um);
    Serial.print("Particles > 10.0 um / 0.1L air:"); Serial.println(data.particles_100um);
    Serial.println("---------------------------------------");  
  }


}
//Dont touch, from internet, needed for the sensor to work properly 
boolean readPMSdata(Stream *s) {
  if (! s->available()) {
    return false;
  }

  // Read a byte at a time until we get to the special '0x42' start-byte
  if (s->peek() != 0x42) {
    s->read();
    return false;
  }

  // Now read all 32 bytes
  if (s->available() < 32) {
    return false;
  }

  uint8_t buffer[32];    
  uint16_t sum = 0;
  s->readBytes(buffer, 32);

  // get checksum ready
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<30; i++) {
    sum += buffer[i];
  }

  /* debugging
  for (uint8_t i=2; i<32; i++) {
    Serial.print("0x"); Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX); Serial.print(", ");
  }
  Serial.println();
  */

  // The data comes in endian'd, this solves it so it works on all platforms
  uint16_t buffer_u16[15];
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<15; i++) {
    buffer_u16[i] = buffer[2 + i*2 + 1];
    buffer_u16[i] += (buffer[2 + i*2] << 8);
  }

  // put it into a nice struct :)
  memcpy((void *)&data, (void *)buffer_u16, 30);

  if (sum != data.checksum) {
    Serial.println("Checksum failure");
    return false; 
  }
  // success!
  return true;
}
```

This is a sample of the data I currently get

```
3/24/2019   14:56:49    0   0   0   0
3/24/2019   14:56:50    12  12  1596    470
3/24/2019   14:56:52    12  12  1596    470
3/24/2019   14:56:53    12  12  1596    470
3/24/2019   14:56:54    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:56:55    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:56:56    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:56:57    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:56:58    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:56:59    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:00    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:01    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:02    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:03    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:04    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:05    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:06    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:08    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:09    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:10    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:11    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:12    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:13    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:14    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:15    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:16    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:17    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:18    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:19    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:20    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:21    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:22    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:23    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:24    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:25    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:26    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:27    13  13  1590    463
3/24/2019   14:57:28    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:29    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:30    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:32    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:33    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:34    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:35    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:36    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:37    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:38    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:39    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:40    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:41    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:42    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:43    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:44    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:45    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:46    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:47    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:48    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:49    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:50    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:51    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:52    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:53    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:54    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:55    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:56    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:57    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:58    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:57:59    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:58:00    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:58:01    11  12  1614    431
3/24/2019   14:58:03    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:58:04    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:58:05    16962   16962   16962   16962
3/24/2019   14:58:06    16962   16962   16962   16962
```

Comment: Can `readBytes` fail?

Comment: I'm not sure. I dont get any error specifically saying it